# Why doesn't Array(n).forEach loop n times?

Tags: javascript, arrays

`Array(3)` yields `[ , , ]`, which has a `length` of 3.

`[1, 2, 3].forEach` loops 3 times, as expected.

Neither `Array(3).forEach` nor `[ , , ].forEach` loops at all, however.

Why is this? I thought I'd discovered a way of doing something `n` times without using `for` loops, and am disappointed to find it doesn't work!

Comment: It's a sparse array.  The unspecified elements are not actually there.  For instance, try iterating over [1,,].  It will loop for the value 1, but not for the two unspecified values.  Or try [1,,3].  It will loop twice with values 1 and 3.

Comment: FYI, you can convert from sparse to non-sparse, using `.apply`: `Array.apply(undefined, Array(3)).forEach(...)` works fine, creating an `Array` of size three with initialized values (of `undefined`, because why not? :-) ) that loops three times as expected.

Comment: You should be looking at [*ECMAScript 2015 Iterator protocols*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). *apply* converts the supplied array to a parameter list and uses a different algorithm to *forEach*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> forEach() executes the provided callback once for each element present
>   in the array in ascending order. It is not invoked for index
>   properties that have been deleted or are uninitialized (i.e. on sparse
>   arrays)

Example from MDN:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dbx02u6/)

```
function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
  console.log('a[' + index + '] = ' + element);
}

// Notice that index 2 is skipped since there is no item at
// that position in the array.
[2, 5, , 9].forEach(logArrayElements);
// logs:
// a[0] = 2
// a[1] = 5
// a[3] = 9
```

[Have a look at MDN article.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

.